# ezrets get total number of images

Tags: php, count, photo, rets

I'm using ezRets inside of php. I am trying to query for the number of images in a listing, given its listing id. I can't do this because I do not know the field name for the number of images

A full query to pass to ezrets would be awesome.

A URL query string to accomplish this in the rets web interface would be appreciated as well.

In the doc I found,
 here is a sample query for the web interface

http:
//(your.rets.server)/rets/server/search?SearchType=Property
&
Class
=ResidentialProperty&QueryType=DMQL2&Format=COMPACT&StandardNames=1
&Select=ListingID,ListPrice&Query=(ListPrice=300000%2B)&Count=1&Limit=10

then it mentions that there is a photo count field, but it does not specify the field name! It is not "PhotoCount" or "PhotoCnt".

Thanks!

Comment: I had this problem too, it is frustrating with some MLS's. [retsmd.com](http://retsmd.com) will return the field names that your RETS server uses.

Comment: Is it safe to give it your login credentials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do first is query the Metadata table for the particular Resource/Class you are looking for the PhotoCount column. These won't be 100% correct since I haven't ever used connectMLS, but you will get the idea.

Use this query to get the metadata for the table Property: 
`http://<connectMLS.rets.server.url>/rets/server/getmetadata?Type=METADATA-
TABLE&Format=COMPACT&Type=Property&Class=ResidentialProperty`

```
 <COLUMNS>
    SystemName    StandardName    LongName    DBName    ShortName    MaximumLength    DataType
  Precision    Searchable
    Interpretation    Alignment    UseSeparator    EditMaskID    LookupName    MaxSelect    Units
  Index    Minimum    Maximum
    Default    Required    SearchHelpID    Unique
 </COLUMNS>
```

One of the available columns above will more than likely have a PICCount or Count or PhotoCounty something related to count. If if doesn't then you will just have to process your returned results and count them yourself.

I hope this helps. It has taken me a little while to wrap my head around RETS.

What particular MLS are you writing queries for?

Comment: this is all I get:
    <RETS ReplyCode="0" ReplyText="Operation Successful">
    <RETS-STATUS ReplyCode="20501" ReplyText="Operation Successful"/>
    </RETS>

Comment: but I think I'm just going to try and use phrets instead, seems to be much easier than querying rets directly.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. You might look into using [librets](http://www.crt.realtors.org/projects/rets/librets/) too. They have [PHP](http://www.crt.realtors.org/projects/rets/librets/documentation/devguide/) support too.

What MLS are you querying? I might have access and can help you.

Comment: [https://github.com/troydavisson/PHRETS/wiki/GetMetadataTable](https://github.com/troydavisson/PHRETS/wiki/GetMetadataTable)

You will want to look at this to find the Photo Count column.

        <?php
        $fields = $rets->GetMetadataTable("Property", "ResidentialProperty");
        foreach ($fields as $field) {
                echo "+ Field {$field['SystemName']} is a {$field['DataType']} type\n";
        }

Are you at 100% sure you have all the right Resource/Class names?

Comment: @SethCohen have you made any progress?

Comment: @SethCohen Not sure this is the same MLS, but a recent MLS used **NumImages** instead of PhotoCount or PicCount. Would be interesting if it was the same MLS. Sorry for all these comments. :D

Comment: most likely just moving to phrets